# Flutter Repaint Boundary repainting rule

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-canvas

I want to repaint my RepaintBoundary widget's child every time the variable `_lastIndex` changes in `setState()` method. Basically, I want the same behaviour for RepaintBoundary as would apply to any normal Container - but for unrelated reasons I need a RepaintBoundary and not a Container. I played around and found out that the child (`MyPainter`) gets re-rendered when `_lastIndex` changes in the first example, but not in the second. What is the rule behind it that makes the behaviors of the two examples so different?

1.example

```
       RepaintBoundary(
          key: globalKey,
          child: Container(
          child: Container(
            child: new CustomPaint(
              child: Text(_lastIndex.toString()), // MyPainter is re-rendered because of this line
              painter: new MyPainter(index: _lastIndex), // while this line doesn't have any effect on re-rendering
              isComplex: true,
              willChange: false,
          ),
         )
        )
      ),
```

2.example

```
 RepaintBoundary(
          key: globalKey,
          child: Container(
          child: Container(
            child: new CustomPaint(
              painter: new MyPainter(index: _lastIndex),
              isComplex: true,
              willChange: false,
          ),
         )
        )
      ),
```

Comment: so you want `RenderBox.markNeedsPaint()` method to be called? in your case `RenderRepaintBoundary.markNeedsPaint()`?

Comment: Yes, that's it! I didn't even know that this method exists, so thank you!!

Comment: but hjonestly if you just want your `CustomPainter` to be "repainted" then use `repaint` parameter in `CustomPainter` constructor - it is much easier imho